# Inconsistent output from Abaqus ODB using Python scripting

Tags: python, abaqus

I'm using a python script to extract and post process results fra an Abaqus FE model, but experience inconsistency when working with data from the odb-file. An example is given below.

```
odbObj = session.openOdb(name=JobName+'.odb', readOnly=True)
step = odbObj.steps['LC5']
set = odbObj.rootAssembly.instances['DETAILEDTOPPLATE-1#TOPPLATE-1'].nodeSets['FD3_N1A']

>>> print 
step.frames[1].fieldOutputs['S'].getSubset(region=set,position=
   ELEMENT_NODAL,elementType='S8R').bulkDataBlocks[0].data
[[  1.29479978e-42  -2.41047720e+07   0.00000000e+00   3.10530625e+05]
 [ -1.08975990e+07  -2.39987960e+07   0.00000000e+00   3.74051719e+05]
 [ -1.10543630e+07  -2.40516500e+07   0.00000000e+00   3.66518000e+05]
 [ -1.10951790e+07  -2.41662480e+07   0.00000000e+00   3.20761438e+05]]
>>> print
step.frames[1].fieldOutputs['S'].getSubset(region=set,position=
   ELEMENT_NODAL,elementType='S8R').bulkDataBlocks[0].data
[[  4.87651866e-43  -2.41047720e+07   0.00000000e+00   3.10530625e+05]
 [ -1.08975990e+07  -2.39987960e+07   0.00000000e+00   3.74051719e+05]
 [ -1.10543630e+07  -2.40516500e+07   0.00000000e+00   3.66518000e+05]
 [ -1.10951790e+07  -2.41662480e+07   0.00000000e+00   3.20761438e+05]]
>>> print 
step.frames[1].fieldOutputs['S'].getSubset(region=set,position=
   ELEMENT_NODAL,elementType='S8R').bulkDataBlocks[0].data
[[  5.60519386e-45   5.60519386e-45   2.38220739e-44   1.92838405e+31]
 [  5.42138869e-11   1.77519978e+28   1.25672711e-14   3.72739562e+05]
 [ -1.10543630e+07  -2.40516500e+07   0.00000000e+00   3.66518000e+05]
 [ -1.10951790e+07  -2.41662480e+07   0.00000000e+00   3.20761438e+05]]
>>> print step.frames[1].fieldOutputs['S'].getSubset(region=set,position=
ELEMENT_NODAL,elementType='S8R').bulkDataBlocks[0].data
[[  2.24207754e-44   5.60519386e-45   0.00000000e+00   3.10530625e+05]
 [ -1.08975990e+07  -2.39987960e+07   0.00000000e+00   3.74051719e+05]
 [ -1.10543630e+07  -2.40516500e+07   0.00000000e+00   3.66518000e+05]
 [ -1.10951790e+07  -2.41662480e+07   0.00000000e+00   3.20761438e+05]]
```

As seen from above the arrays are not consistent even though the call is exactly the same and thus the data should be identical. I can understand and accept that the really small numbers vary, but all sizes of numbers change.

I hope someone can help solve this problem or give a work around.

Thanks in advance.

#### Additional information based on comments.

Two workarounds have been suggest (examples shown below is with another data set than above). Method 1) solves the problem.

1) tmp=x.bulkDataBlocks which does the job

```
tmp=step.frames[1].fieldOutputs['S'].getSubset(
   region=set,position=ELEMENT_NODAL,elementType='S8R').bulkDataBlocks
print tmp[0].data
[[-20119512.     -7074813.5           0.     -2039073.375]
 [-20130472.     -7037518.            0.     -1930314.125]
 [-20122654.     -6948099.            0.     -2073283.625]
 [-20107980.     -6968545.5           0.     -1941211.375]]
print tmp[0].data
[[-20119512.     -7074813.5           0.     -2039073.375]
 [-20130472.     -7037518.            0.     -1930314.125]
 [-20122654.     -6948099.            0.     -2073283.625]
 [-20107980.     -6968545.5           0.     -1941211.375]]
print tmp[0].data
[[-20119512.     -7074813.5           0.     -2039073.375]
 [-20130472.     -7037518.            0.     -1930314.125]
 [-20122654.     -6948099.            0.     -2073283.625]
 [-20107980.     -6968545.5           0.     -1941211.375]]
```

2) tmp=np.copy(x.bulkDataBlocks) which makes even more inconsistency

```
tmp=np.copy(step.frames[1].fieldOutputs['S'].getSubset(
   region=set,position=ELEMENT_NODAL,elementType='S8R').bulkDataBlocks)
print tmp[0].data
[[  2.24207754e-44   5.60519386e-45   0.00000000e+00  -1.78478850e+06]
 [ -1.63939740e+07  -7.07835200e+06   0.00000000e+00  -1.76956088e+06]
 [ -1.63960690e+07  -7.07548150e+06   0.00000000e+00  -1.79225850e+06]
 [ -1.63969780e+07  -7.07681000e+06   0.00000000e+00  -1.79695375e+06]]
print tmp[0].data
[[  1.68155816e-44   5.60519386e-45   0.00000000e+00  -1.78478850e+06]
 [ -1.63939740e+07  -7.07835200e+06   0.00000000e+00  -1.76956088e+06]
 [ -1.63960690e+07  -7.07548150e+06   0.00000000e+00  -1.79225850e+06]
 [ -1.63969780e+07  -7.07681000e+06   0.00000000e+00  -1.79695375e+06]]
print tmp[0].data
[[  5.60519386e-45   5.60519386e-45   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: what do you get if you look at `fieldobject.values[i].data?

Comment: From values[i].data I get the correct and consistent data, so this seems to be the solution. Thank you!

Can you explain the difference between the data in bulkDataBlocks and in values?

A problem with values compared to bulkDataBlocks, is with values I cannot tell if the output is on the positive or negative side of the shell elements where I extract data from...

Comment: I've never tried `bulkDataBlocks`. Will try it on my own code when I get a chance.

Comment: I've gotten inconsistent results indexing `bulkDataBlocks` directly as well.  My workaround was to set `foo = x.bulkDataBlocks`, `print foo[0].data`  This seems to indicate that the `_getitem_` method of `bulkDataBlocks` is faulty somehow.

Comment: The workaround with foo=x.bulkDataBlocks did the job and I now have consistent data. Thank you so much Daniel F!

Comment: There are also other bugs to when accesing data with the bulkDataBlocks method. Always copy the returned numpy array (np.copy(...)) or you will soon run into another weird bugs...

Comment: I actually experience even more inconsistency when using np.copy. See the example in the edited question above (too many characters to show here)

Comment: Oh thats's clear. You np.copy a Abaqus object instead of the data in it. I don't know why this is even possible... Try

tmp=step.frames[1].fieldOutputs['S'].getSubset(region=set,position=ELEMENT_NODAL,elementType='S8R').bulkDataBlocks

tmp_data=np.copy(tmp[0].data) #That get's you the array.

Comment: From the [`C++` docs](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt02ch61pyo05.html#ker-fieldbulkdata-cpp) the `data` attribute of a `fieldBulkData` object is a pointer.  Judging by the strange performance, this is likely a *relative* pointer that's not correctly handled by `python`'s native or  `numpy`'s  modified `_getitem_` methods, but is correctly handled by `abaqus`'s `sequence` object's `_getitem_` method.  But you can't use that method until you have a `sequence` - if you try to index `bulkDataBlocks` directly you use `python`'s `_getitem_`.  Maybe?

Comment: Are the values the same if you check them using the CAE/Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're looking at extrapolation errors (which could be caused by issues with your mesh or analysis setup). Note that ELEMENT_NODAL data is generally extrapolated from the integration points used in the analysis each time the data is requested, unless it has been explicitly stored as a field output for the job.

See the [Abaqus Scripting User's Guide](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/cmd/default.htm?startat=pt05ch10s10.html) (section 10.10.8) for more info:

> If the requested field values are not found in the output database at the specified odb_Enum::ELEMENT_NODAL or odb_Enum::CENTROID positions, they are extrapolated from the field data at the odb_Enum::INTEGRATION_POINT position.

Comment: could be. You'd think the extrapolation would be the same if you repeat it though.

Comment: It could might be the problem. I did a small test requesting data only from the integration points and there it doesn't seem to be a problem. Very small numbers in the range 1e-6 to 1e-50 still change though, but that's ok.

As agentp mentions you'd think the extrapolation would be the same when repeating the call.

I think I'll dig a bit deeper into the problem and return with any usefull information.